# Class 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have changed my application by using  command

`php artisan app:name [app_name]`.

Then, when I try to perform other actions using following artisan commands,

```
php artisan down

php artisan up

php artisan config:cache
```

I got the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found
```

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Worth trying this: "composer dump-autoload" from your project root.

Comment: I tried.Still i am getting same error

Comment: Look into `bootstrap/cache` directory, and empty it, if there is something.

Comment: @max.lanin:Thanks.It is working now.Actually what was the problem?

Comment: At the end of the installation process composer/installer automatically calls `php artisan optimize` command that compiles your app into one file to optimize classes autoload. If it is presented, Laravel uses it by default. After you changed your app name, your namespace was changed and cached version becomes outdated with its old namespace, and this exception starts  throwing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is working after Clearing  **`bootstrap/cache`** directory.

Comment: Thank you man. After trying all the solutions. This one worked.

Answer (score 4):

This is how its worked out for me in the case of a fresh install.

First, I cleared the files in **boostrap\cache**.

Then, in config\app.php, I added the below line in the providers,

```
 \Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class,
```

Then I ran the below commands

```
php artisan telescope:install
php artisan migrate
```

And it was working after this.
I don't know for what reason the telescope provider didn't work which was added by Laravel itself. i.e  `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class`.

By the way my laravel version was **7.12.0**.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, some extension of the VSCode, added a `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;` at the beginning of the file `/config/app.php`.

I solved it by removing the line from the file and running `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted the folder called providers
App/providers.

[image]

Comment: Otherwise inadvertently moving it into another folder. Check it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a question like yours then I solved it by copying app/providers directory from another Laravel project to my project thus it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by,

migrate migration file - `vendor>laravel>telescope>database>`- manually.
check `app.php` file, if `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class`, exist or not, have to exist
Run in command shell>

```
npm run dev
```