# After Renamimg app name getting FatalThrowableError

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel-5.3. After renaming the app when I'm trying to start the server I'm getting the following error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Class
>   'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found

What should i do? I am new at Laravel.

Comment: I think, you should search for an already existing answer. Have you visited any of these links ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297358/class-app-providers-appserviceprovider-not-found/33898249, https://laravel.io/forum/07-22-2015-after-changeing-appname-class-appprovidersappserviceprovider-not-found, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/class-appprovidersappserviceprovider-not-found,

Comment: I have checked this link and i have tried there way. They solved it by clearing bootstrap/cache directory. But after doing this i am getting a lot of error. I would comment there but i don't have required reputation to do so. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Mutasim Fuad when you create an app - the app name is automatically generated in multiple parts of your project - this error implies that you changed only the app name (and not related code such as classes)

Comment: i Have checked my model and controller classes. The namespace has been changed to the new name automatically. Can tell me where else to check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297358/class-app-providers-appserviceprovider-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have your configuration cached. You can solve it with the artisan command 'config:cache':

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Before this, make sure that you have the correct namespaces in your application.