# how to remove jetstream and fortify in laravel?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I am trying to remove Fortify and Jetstream packages from Laravel so I removed them from App. Providers, from composer.json (require section), Actions, Config, vendor. Then I run composer update and I get the following message:

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

I also remove sanctium from the same locations

Comment: The first step should've been: `composer remove laravel/jetstream`

Answer (score 8):

Only remove from `composer.json` file won't delete them fully. You need to remove and modify some file manually.

**Edit away**

```
app/Http/Kernel.php - \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
app/Models/User.php - use HasProfilePhoto;
config/app.php - App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
config/app.php - App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider::class,
routes/web.php - routes with auth:sanctum
```

**Delete**

```
app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php
app/Providers/JetstreamServiceProvider.php
app/View/Components/AppLayout.php
app/View/Components/GuestLayout.php
app/Actions/Fortify/
app/Actions/Jetstream/

config/fortify.php
config/jetstream.php
config/sanctum.php
```

I'm using Laravel 8. The solution may differ depending on the version.

Comment: Don't forget to clean up the /database/migrations (ie. two_factor_auth) & migrate fresh (if you can afford to lose the data)

Answer (score 1):

You May also Clear the bootstrap/cache directory.
[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33898249/1304811)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Remove the Modified Files From Your Project after that Remove it From your `composer.json` and run the following Command

```
composer remove vendor/package
```

Running the following command will remove the package from vendor composer.json and composer.lock

And After that Run `Composer Update` thats all

Answer (score 1):

Yea, supporting the first answer to this question. Removing it manually might be stressful and overwhelming, but what I did in my own case is very simple because after installing and uninstalling Laravel Jetstream, over 80 files and folders created still remain in my code base. I had to push only my changes to the repo;

`git add` 'each file'

`git commit -m` "your messages"

`git checkout -b` 'your new local branch name'

`git push --set-upstream origin` 'the same name as above line'

Then, I raised PR to the main brand to merge, after merging. Then, I switch to the main branch and checkout from the main branch with the below code.

`git checkout origin` 'your safe branch name'

`git checkout -b` 'your new safe local branch name' to continue your good work.

Hopefully, this is helpful to someone. Thanks